# Clean URL not working properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hey I'm struggling with this all day long and I'm new to clean URLs.

My Domain which i want to change:

```
http://www.domain.tld/ausflug.php?lang=de
```

to:

```
http://www.domain.tld/ausflug/lang/de/
```

via .htaccess. This is my code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ausflug/lang/(.*)/ ausflug.php?lang=$1
```

My Problems are:

- If I navigate through my page, the url still is the ugly one.
- And if I want to reach the page with the clean url, it won't display all the
  css and js stuff.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, replace your current code by this one (your htaccess should be in root folder)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/ausflug\.php\?lang=([a-z]{2}) [NC]
RewriteRule . /ausflug/lang/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^ausflug/lang/([a-z]{2})/$ /ausflug.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

This will redirect `domain.tld/ausflug.php?lang=de` to `domain.tld/ausflug/lang/de/` and will internally rewrite it (without any redirection loop error) to `domain.tld/ausflug.php?lang=de`.

For your second problem:

> if I want to reach the page with the clean url, it won't display all
>   the css and js stuff

Simply use **absolute** paths for your links (with a leading slash).

Example: `/css/file.css` instead of `css/file.css` (otherwise it will look in wrong directory, since your rule is generating some virtual directories)

Or you can add this html tag `<base href="/">` right after `<head>` in all pages (instead of replacing each links)

Comment: I just got one problem left. Do I need to change all files like that? css/file.css to /css.file.css or is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: There's another way. You can add this html tag `<base href="/">` right after `<head>` in your pages